# Is there a reason for linux-image-*-generic being marked manual by default and can this be changed?

Tags: apt, package-management

I noticed today that my linux images were stacking up on the hard drive (Ubuntu Server 12.04).  I freed up a couple of GB in clearing the majority of them off.

When I looked into this there is a script in place to protect the current version (current running, most recent, second most recent). This is run automatically each time a new linux image is added through apt: `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`.  It's effect is to prevent the most relevant images from being removed automatically through apt.

However this did not explain the number of images I had filling up my `/boot` partition. This appears due to each `linux-image-*-generic` being marked as `manual` in apt so that you need to use `apt-mark auto linux-image-3.2.0-32-generic` before it will be identified for removal.

Is there any simple way to change this behavior so that kernels are only retained by the logic in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`?  Is it inadvisable to try?

Comment: hmm, it doesn't do that on 13.04 desktop... might be fixed in 13.04 and/or is just a thing with the server version.

Comment: If memory serves me right, is a protection that kernels don't get removed automatically, because if something goes wrong with a new kernel, you could use the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this behavior changed later on. Right now the kernels are marked in Auto and [removed when they start to pollute](https://askubuntu.com/q/369105/169736). This is to start removing them and don't fill up the `/boot` partition.