# What is Ubuntu's policy on keeping old kernels

Tags: kernel, package-management

I've just run out of disk space on /. Looking into the situation I realised that since first installing 12.04, Ubuntu has upgraded the kernel ~23 times and **has kept every old kernel, binaries and header sources**.

I've just manually `apt-get purge`-ed all but the last couple, saving ~4Gb space (on a 20Gb partition, so that's v. significant). Why would Ubuntu want to keep all of those? Is it lack of a feature such as "keep last 4" or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ubuntu used to keep the old kernels around for safety reasons, however it should be autocleaning old kernels now.

The system should be auto cleaning old kernels per this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/923876

So you might want to ensure that your system is up to date and that you have apt (0.9.7.5ubuntu5.5) installed. If you're still getting the wrong behavior then please [report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on the apt package.

This is also useful if you want to clean up stuff:

- [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

You don't need to manually purge each kernel package, doing a `sudo apt-get autoremove` every once in a while  will remove kernels you don't need anymore. However finding the root cause as to why your system isn't autocleaning old kernels is probably easier.